# Difference between angularjs-nvd3-directives vs angular-nvd3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, angularjs-directive, angularjs-nvd3-directives

I would need any suggestion help or whatever. I am doing BI tools with new technologies and I am really interesting on them, even participating 
in one of these project.
However, I would like to know a priori pros and cons

Links

https://github.com/angularjs-nvd3-directives/angularjs-nvd3-directives

https://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3

Thx

Comment: Did you reach a conclusion on this?

Answer (score 4):

I'm faced with this same question and I thought I would share my thoughts. I'm going with https://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3. As of today, the most recent push on github was 15 days ago. The other choice hasn't been pushed for 8 months. In addition, angular-nvd3 has great examples and more documentation. As Vincent said, they both use nvd3 as the engine, so you'll probably get the same amount of performance. But for usability, I'll take recently updated and lots of examples.

Answer (score 3):

I was investigating the same two. Both seem promising, and accessible.

My preference: Angular-nvD3 - more control;

The charting engine is the same (nvd3).

angular-nvD3:

- full range of charts - same as nvd3
- Just a shell around nvd3
- you will do most of your work in java (behind the scenes)
- In the front-end working with one nvd3 directive, and in the backend - you configure elaborate 'options' and 'data' objects.

nvD3-directvies:

- wide, but smaller range of charts (check websites)
- More declarative: range of nvd3 directives (one for each chart); options are declared as attributes
- more natural to link to separate model variables

I might update this answer when I learn more.

Comment: It seems like angularjs-nvd3-directives has stopped development, I was having trouble with a bug then I saw that it's last PR to master was 10 months ago

Answer (score 1):

With *angular-nvd3-directives* since a lot of the config options are attributes,  it can be slightly slower since angular will be watching for any changes on any of the directive attributes. Another con is that the directives file is larger  (un-minified 115kb).

I prefer "angular-nvd3" as the json options can be created as a service and configured and accessed much faster. Also, having worked heavily in angular-highcharts, this is the best way of having a charting directive. It is also smaller (u-nminified 29.1kb)